# jQuery Autocomplete for multiple input fields

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Hey guys, 
I've downloaded an auto-complete script in jQuery from formvega (http://www.fromvega.com) and I've encountered a problem. I want to make this work for several input fields and I've tried to make it work buy linking it to input classes. The problem is that when I do so it the first form fills all the other forms with the same content. I guess it's some problem with the variables in .js-file but I canät seem to figure out what it is.

Here is some code form the .js file:

```
var acListTotal   =  0;
var acListCurrent = -1;
var acDelay = 500;
var acURL   = null;
var acSearchId = null;
var acResultsId = null;
var acSearchField = null;
var acResultsDiv  = null;

function setAutoComplete(field_class, results_id, get_url ){
// initialize vars
acSearchId  = "." + field_class;
acResultsId = "#" + results_id;
acURL       = get_url;

// create the results div
$("body").append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');

// register mostly used vars
acSearchField   = $(acSearchId);
acResultsDiv    = $(acResultsId);

// reposition div
repositionResultsDiv();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the actually code where you apply the autocomplete to a textbox. However I can assume it is similar to this.

```
<input type="text" class="auto-complete" />
<input type="text" class="auto-complete" />
<input type="text" class="auto-complete" />
```

.

```
$(".auto-complete").autoComplete({... options ...});
```

you would need to loop through them so they are set as their own scope

```
$texts = $(".auto-complete");
$.each($text, function(i, val) {
    $(val).autoComplete({... options ...});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
The code is:
`$(function(){
  setAutoComplete("searchField", "results","autocomplete2.php?part=" );
});
<input type="text" class="searchField" />
<input type="text" class="searchField" />`
Can I still use your code suggestion?

Comment: I updated your question, but I still don't see the actual call when you attach the autocomplete to a textbox?

Comment: Bobby, I'm quite a noob at this stuff. The call is: `<input class="searchField" name="departfrom" id="searchField" required="required" type="text" title="Where are you departing from?">`. The form input class should be the call, right?

Comment: Okey! Found a better way of making this work. Trial and error!